# How to show javascript alert with string val in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, alert

I am trying to show an alert in my jsp page with the following code.

```
<%
---------------
---------------
out.write("<script type='text/javascript'>\n");
out.write("alert('Hello')");
out.write("</script>\n");
---------------
---------------
%>
```

Everything is working fine. Alert is coming when page is loading.
Now  I want to show an alert with string variable. For this I changed the above code to below. Now  the alert is not coming.

```
<%
---------------
---------------
String name = (String) application.getAttribute("name");
System.out.println("name = "+name);
out.write("<script type='text/javascript'>\n");
out.write("alert('Hello'+name)");
out.write("</script>\n");
---------------
---------------
%>
```

Could you please tell me how to add string variable to the above alert function.

Answer (score 2):

Correct your code like below

```
out.write("alert('Hello+" + name + "')");
```

Comment: I have changed the code, but I am not getting any alert. Directly the jsp page is displaying.

Comment: Can you try with String name = "test";

Comment: If I am testing with static string value, the alert is coming, But when appending java variable to that static value, alert is not coming

Comment: Can you debug or print out the application.getAttribute("name") to see if it has a value?

Comment: yes , the value is coming. I am printing on console.

Comment: Can you share the new code now? how you have typed it in?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70617/discussion-between-jerome-anthony-and-user2636874).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this with EL without jsp scriplets:

```
<script>
    alert('Hello ${applicationScope.name}');
</script>
```

OR

```
<script>
    alert('Hello ${name}');
</script>
```

**P.S.** Do not use application scope to store user specific values, its shared among the different sessions(users). Try HttpSession or HttpServletRequest instead.

**EDIT**

```
<%
   out.write("<script>");
   out.write("alert(\"Hello " + application.getAttribute("name") + "\")");
   out.write("</script>");
%>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I want to show an alert within the scriptlets only

Comment: In the above code I initialized the string variable name with some value. after that I try to show an alert with name.

Comment: I have checked that one, instead of showing an alert it is adding the output to jsp page itself

Comment: @user2636874, kindly find my updated post, did you got the value of `name`?